# Many-to-Many query problems

Tags: ms-access

I'm fairly new to the access world and all my knowledge has been gathered from dissecting templates and multiple google searches, so bear with me please!
Ive done my searches and have found many examples but I'm not sure if they do what I need, one was similar to what I'm asking but I just couldnt translate his results to mine.

First a quick review of what I'm trying to accomplish; I'm trying to create a query that lists each position and the skills that accompany that position.  Most of the positions have the same required skills, but each one also has a unique skill that others done.  For example; QB has speed, agility, acceleration, strength, awareness, throwing accuracy and throwing power associated with it.  RB has speed, agility, acceleration, strength, awareness, ball carry vision, and elusiveness associated with it.

I have three tables; Positions(lists all the positions), Skills(lists all the skills), and PositionSkills(a many-to-many table that lists each position and what skills are associated with it).  Tables are like this:

```
PositionID(PK)|AutoNumber
Position      |Short Text

SkillID(PK)   |AutoNumber
SkillName     |Short Text

PositionID(PK)|Number
SkillID(PK)   |Number
```

I'm trying to create a query That returns the position and each skill that falls under it.  The problem is, my query always returns listing each positions multiple times with a different skill beside it, when I want it to list the position one time, which each skill after it.

```
Position(QB) | Skill | Skill | Skill | Skill 
Position(RB) | Skill | Skill | Skill | Skill
Position(WR) | Skill | Skill | Skill | Skill
```

Eventually, I would like to create a form where users input general details about players and select the Position from a combobox.  The bottom of the form will show skills related to the position that is selected in the combobox.
Any help is greatly appreciated, if more info is needed point me to it and I will provide it
Thank You!

Comment: Can you please include the query as you currently have it written, and a brief description of what you are currently using to output the results?

Comment: I haven't currently got a query written, as I thought it would be a lot more simple, I used Access 2013's Simple Query Wizard to build one in which it returned the results described above, multiples of the same positions with each different skill associated, instead of the skill listed once with each associated skill next to it.  I'll edit my post to be more helpful

Comment: Your question is tagged with mysql, but from what you've said it sounds like you may be referring to MS Access. Is that right?

Comment: The tag system had me all confused.  I couldnt put my own tag in, and it said to choose from the suggested list.  Sorry, just realized that the tag suggestions pop up when you type something.  Corrected, and use I am using access 2013

Comment: @Don'tPanic I'm taking a guess here.  Do I create the parent form with the combobox for position, and then create an AfterUpdate event on the combobox to set subform filters showing only the skills associated with that position?

Comment: I'm rather out of practice with Access, but that sounds like a reasonable approach. A query that lists each position multiple times with a different skill beside it actually sounds like a decent recordset for a subform. If you link it to the parent form by position, and then use your combobox event to find the position record on the parent form, I think it should work pretty well.

Comment: It should work, I just need to find out what I am doing wrong with the subform.  Its created, and it is linked, but every text box in the form shows the same skill instead of each different one associated.  I want the subform to be data entry, where users input a score next to the skill, eventually, after a lot of math it would give a final value for that player

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, you should be able to do something like this - generate a list like you're wanting. This would be for MySQL though...

```
SELECT 
Position,
GROUP_CONCAT(SkillName) as Skills
FROM Positions
LEFT JOIN PositionSkills USING(PositionID)
LEFT JOIN Skills USING(SkillID)
GROUP BY PositionID
```

Comment: You're flavor of SQL may be slightly different, I'm not sure. This is kind of a neat place to set up scenarios and test them: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Maybe I dont need to query to be done?  What do you think?  Im creating a form for people to put details in, then select a position from a combobox.  depending on the position they select, the corresponding skills for that position show up in a subform attached to the main.

Comment: well, depends I guess on how much data you have. Personally, if it isn't a whole lot of data then you might consider just making a json or xml array in a file to store your data. That can be just as fast without so much complication.